# Problema con java y los directorios en linux al ejecutar archivo jar. No abre el directorio actual y abre el directorio home del usuario

Tags: java, linux, windows, archivo, rutas

Tengo un programa empaquetado en archivo Jar que al ejecutarlo haciendo doble clic, debe abrir el explorador de archivos en el directorio actual pero abre el directorio home de linux. Lo mismo pasa cuando intento crear un fichero en el directorio actual, lo crea en el directorio home del usuario.
El problema surge cuando ejecuto el archivo Jar haciendo doble clic, ya que si lo ejecuto desde el terminal de linux con el comando "java -jar archivo.jar" se ejecuta sin problemas y todas las funciones como abrir el directorio actual o crear un archivo en el directorio actual lo hace sin problemas. En este caso, el problema es que paralelo al programa me queda una ventana del terminal abierta uqe si la cierro, me mata el programa en cuestion. (ya intenté ejecutarlo como un procesoen segundo plano pero igualmente la ventana del terminal debe seguir abierta)

Debajo el codigo de ejemplo:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.awt.Desktop;

 public class abrirDirectorioActual{
   public static void main(String[]args){
    try{
       String sDirecotrioActual = System.getProperty("user.dir");
       File objetofile = new File(sDirectorioActual);
       Desktop.getDesktop().open(objetofile);
       }catch(Exception e){
       }
   }
}
```

No funciona si esta empaquetado en un archivo Jar y ejecutado desde el archivo, pero si funciona si ejecuto el char con un comando desde el terminal

Comment: `System.getProperty("user.dir");` devuelve el directorio actual en el que el usuario está ejecutando el programa (en otras palabras, el directorio donde estás parado en tu terminal), en lugar del directorio donde está el programa. ¿Por casualidad no estarás ejecutando el programa desde el `home`?

Comment: Hola Jaime. No, lo ejecute en diferentes directorios. En otra unidad de otro disco, en distintos directorios, siempre asume que esta en el home. Desde el proyecto en netbeans, funciona bien, pero despues de compilar y crear un archivo jar, el archivo jar ejecuta todo como si estuviese en el home.

Comment: ¿Usas AWT/Swing/JavaFX? ¿Es un jar firmado?

Comment: Hola Sal. Uso algunas clases con Swing, pero ni JavaFX ni AWT. Y no está firmado.

Answer (score 0):

Te estará pasando el directorio `home` por la ubicación de tu programa java.

Te dejo una recomendación de una buena practica que podrías aplicar:

Lo primero de todo, deberías usar buenas practicas y acceder a los ficheros del `ClassPath`, es decir aquellos que este manejando el entorno de tu aplicación.
Si lo puedes hacer de esta manera, te recomiendo que lo hagas.
Primero coloca tu archivo en la carpeta `resources`, (si es estructura `maven`)
Para acceder ahora a los archivos del `ClassPath` a través de java, se hace a través del cargador de clases. Es decir, a través de los metadatos de la clase (.class) recoge el `getClassLoader()`

Si requieres un ImputStream puedes hacer algo como...

`new InputStreamReader(NombreClase.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("ruta de tu archivo (solo )"))`

y con el InputStreamReader haces lo que necesites.

Espero que pueda servirte :-)

Comment: Hola Carlos, el programa lo tengo empaquetado en un archivo Jar, que es cuando ocurre el problema. Si compilo y ejecuto el archivo .class funciona, pero al empaquetarlo en el archivo Jar me redirige todo al home.